# Meaning of the third argument in png_read_row(s)?

Tags: c, libpng

In libpng there are several functions provided that allow reading of the image on the by-row basis.

Here is how they are declared:

```
void png_read_row (png_structp png_ptr, png_bytep row,    png_bytep display_row)
void png_read_rows (png_structp png_ptr, png_bytepp row,    png_bytepp display_row, png_uint_32 num_rows)
```

What is the meaning of their third arguments? In libpng manual they are set to NULL, where their usage is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libpng12.png.read.row.1.html):

`"display_row" is used to display a blurred progressive image. "display_row" can be NULL if the progressive image is not required.`

Comment: So that's wheere the reference is! Thank you very much.